# Magento2 - add a small jquery which was working fine before upgrade

Tags: jquery, magento2

The code which I am using is like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if(window.location.href =='https://mysite/csproduct/vproducts/new/set/4/type/simple/'){
    console.log('ready');
    $("[name='product[vendor_price]']").keyup(function() {
    $("[name='product[price]']").val($(this).val()).change();
    });
    }
});
```

If I paste the code in console, it works.
even without pasting the code I am getting 
`console.log` - ready.
besides this there is no error in console.

HTML which is used here is like this:

```
<div class="admin__field _required" data-bind="css: $data.additionalClasses, attr: {'data-index': index}, visible: visible" data-index="vendor_price">       
<label class="admin__field-label" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}, visible: $data.labelVisible" for="CTK9J41">

<span data-bind="attr: {'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel}, text: label" data-config-scope="[STORE VIEW]">Vendor Price</span>
</label>   

<div class="admin__field-control" data-bind="css: {'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip, '_with-reset': $data.showFallbackReset &amp;&amp; $data.isDifferedFromDefault}">
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text" data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
    }" name="product[vendor_price]" aria-describedby="notice-CTK9J41" id="CTK9J41">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="admin__field admin__field-small _required" data-bind="css: $data.additionalClasses, attr: {'data-index': index}, visible: visible" data-index="price">
```

```
<span data-bind="attr: {'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel}, text: label" data-config-scope="[STORE VIEW]">Price</span>
    </label>

<div class="admin__field-control" data-bind="css: {'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip, '_with-reset': $data.showFallbackReset &amp;&amp; $data.isDifferedFromDefault}">

<div class="admin__control-addon">                

<input class="admin__control-text" type="text" data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
    }" name="product[price]" aria-describedby="notice-JHLHU2O" id="JHLHU2O">   

<label class="admin__addon-prefix" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}" for="JHLHU2O">

<span data-bind="text: addbefore">₹</span>
</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is *not* working? Could you provide the HTML that goes with it, so we could reproduce the problem?

Comment: sure I will add the html, though little complex being generated by magento. what is not working - when I type in the field `vendor-price` the same should be copied to `product-price`

Comment: I don't see any field `vendor_price` in your HTML .... What *does* exist is `artist_price`. Maybe there is a confusion?

Comment: yah actually I had replace the artist price with vendor price, now I have replaced in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento 2 uses the Knockout.js framework to dynamically build some parts of it's frontend. This building will happen also after the jQuery `ready` event fires. So it may be that the element with `name='product[vendor_price]'` is not yet available in the DOM when you look for it.

One way to make your event listener work is to use [*event delegation* with `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on("keyup", "[name='product[vendor_price]']", function() {
    $("[name='product[price]']").val($(this).val()).change();
});
```

NB: unrelated to your question, but try using the "input" event instead of "keyup": that will also respond to changes made via drag-n-drop, via the context menu (clear, cut, paste), via other input devices, or when a key is kept down and is repeating.

Comment: A big thank you trincot. without your help, I cannot imagine, I could have solved it. Perfect.